# Wi-Fi not working with BCM43142 after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

Here is the link for all my Wi-Fi Related details:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PTFHmrrHw9/

I can see it in `iwlist scan` but I am not able to connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

Please edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

And remove the following content

```
iface wlp8s0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.1.241
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
braodcast 192.168.1.255
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the driver and reboot:
`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo reboot`.

Upon rebooting, run:
`sudo modprobe wl` to load the driver.